# How to monitor Apache Mesos?

Tags: mesos

I run a Mesos production instance.

It is important to keep this system up and running.

Is it possible to setup some sort of monitoring around a TCP/HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

```
http://<fqdn>:5050/master/health
```

That API returns HTTP Status code 200 for GET calls.

One could use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) or other alternatives to monitor a Mesos Master

Comment: I found some videos may be helpful for you. * [Per Container Network Monitoring and Isolation in Mesos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA96g1M4v8Y&index=38&list=PLVjgeV_avap2arug3vIz8c6l72rvh9poV) * [How to Monitor Mesos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlgAT_xFNzU&index=7&list=PLVjgeV_avap2arug3vIz8c6l72rvh9poV) * [Satellite: A Monitoring Application for Mesos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLkc17HFEb8&index=2&list=PLVjgeV_avap2arug3vIz8c6l72rvh9poV)